# Using \pgfplotstablesort with a dynamically named macro

Tags: expansion, pgfplotstable

I have a moderately large number of data files that I need to read in with `\pgfplotstablesort`, and in each case the data read in should be assigned to a macro for later use in a plot. The filenames follow a predictable pattern so I would like to make a macro that reads the data and assigns it to a macro whose name is related to the filename. So far I've been working with this:

```
\def\readdata#1#2#3#4{
 \def\filenamepattern##1{#1}
 \pgfplotstablesort{\csname #4himu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#3}}
 \pgfplotstablesort{\csname #4lomu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#2}}
 % other stuff
}
\readdata{testfile#1.dat}{10}{50}{testdata}
```

This doesn't compile, of course, because `\pgfplotstablesort` can't handle the `\csname` in the first argument. PDFLaTeX spits out lots of errors, starting with `Missing \begin{document}`, and never terminates. I know that's the root of the problem because if I put in that macro name manually,

```
\def\readdata#1#2#3#4{
 \def\filenamepattern##1{#1}
 \pgfplotstablesort{\testdatahimu}{\filenamepattern{#3}}
 \pgfplotstablesort{\testdatalomu}{\filenamepattern{#2}}
 % other stuff
}
```

it works fine.

So now I try an `\expandafter`, thinking that it will cause `\csname...\endcsname` to be expanded before `\pgfplotstablesort`:

```
\def\readdata#1#2#3#4{
 \def\filenamepattern##1{#1}
 \expandafter\pgfplotstablesort{\csname #4himu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#3}}
 \expandafter\pgfplotstablesort{\csname #4lomu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#2}}
 % other stuff
}
```

but that doesn't make any change. I guess this has something to do with the definition of `\pgfplotstablesort`, perhaps how it can take an optional argument, but I get lost trying to figure it out.

Can anyone show me if there's some way to get what I'm trying to do to work, and  preferably explain why the `\expandafter` I tried didn't make it happen? I would like to use this as an opportunity to better understand macro expansion, in addition to actually being able to load my data files for plotting.

---

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{testfile10.dat}
pT Y mu2 lomean lostddev loerrbound nlomean nlostddev nloerrbound
0.35 2.2 10 2.8920929e+00 0 1.7555822e-04 1.1823986e+00 1.6578794e-01 6.7619291e-02
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{testfile50.dat}
pT Y mu2 lomean lostddev loerrbound nlomean nlostddev nloerrbound
0.35 2.2 10 2.8920929e+00 0 1.7555822e-04 1.1823986e+00 1.6578794e-01 6.7619291e-02
\end{filecontents*}

\def\readdata#1#2#3#4{
 \def\filenamepattern##1{#1}
 \pgfplotstablesort{\csname #4himu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#3}}
 \pgfplotstablesort{\csname #4lomu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#2}}
 % other stuff
}
\readdata{testfile#1.dat}{10}{50}{testdata}
\begin{document} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymode=log]
   \addplot table[x=pT,y=lomean] {\testdatahimu};
   \addplot table[x=pT,y=lomean] {\testdatalomu};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are expanding the left brace, you need another `\expandafter` for that too. Like @egreg I'm puzzled about the `\filenamepattern` is it for placing dynamically the numbers 10, 50?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that

```
\newcommand\readdata[4]{%
  \def\filenamepattern##1{#1}%
  \expandafter\pgfplotstablesort\csname #4himu\endcsname{\filenamepattern{#3}}%
  \expandafter\pgfplotstablesort\csname #4lomu\endcsname{\filenamepattern{#2}}%
  % other stuff
}
\readdata{testfile#1.dat}{10}{50}{testdata}
```

will do, since `\pgfplotstablesort` will be presented with a macro name.

Why didn't your `\expandafter` work? Because you tried to expand a brace. If a brace is necessary (I don't think so), use

```
\expandafter\pgfplotstablesort\expandafter{\csname #4himu\endcsname}{\filenamepattern{#3}}%
```

I'm unsure about the role of `\filenamepattern`, but the macro are yours.

Comment: The `filenamepattern` is for constructing the filenames `testfile10.dat` and `testfile50.dat` from the template `testfile#1.dat` (which will vary from one use to another). Why, is there some better way to do it?

Comment: @DavidZ You're defining `\filenamepattern` to ignore its argument and always use the first argument to `\readdata`.

Comment: The first argument to `\readdata` will always have a `#1` in it; that's where the argument to `\filenamepattern` (10 or 50 in this case) comes in.